# git fetch: default to something other than origin

Tags: git

I've read in a number of places that simply executing `git fetch` will default to fetching `origin`, and that if you have no remote called `origin`, the fetch will fail with

```
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
```

Is it possible to default git to fetch something other than `origin`? I prefer to name my remotes a little more descriptively (like `gitlab` or `bitbucket`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`origin` is just the default name for the default remote, just like `master` is the default name for the default branch. But none of that is set in stone, and you can easily change it. It’s perfectly fine to work with a repository that has neither an `origin` remote nor a `master` branch.

[`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) will default to using `origin` if no remote name is specified *and* if there’s no upstream remote configured for the current branch.

So in order to have `git fetch` fetch from a different remote, you need to set up your branch to track the remote’s remote branch, for example by doing the following:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=github/master
```